# LaTeX support in community blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

Not sure if this should be separate from the other blog-related threads. I started fooling around with the new blog and drafting a post. However, I can't seem to get LaTeX to work... I am not an expert on WordPress, but I understand that there are LaTeX packages, like these two:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latex/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-latex/

Is it possible to load one for the community blog (that way we can add math)? Or am I missing some obvious feature that is already present?

Answer (score 5):

Bugs, feature requests, etc regarding the community blog are fine here. (:

We already had the [Mathjax Latex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mathjax-latex/) plugin installed on the blog network, I just needed to enable it on the cstheory blog.

The [plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mathjax-latex/) talks about the syntax, so if you're having issues using it, make sure you check that out.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Rebecca!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is [Mathjax Latex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mathjax-latex/) which would enable the blog to use the same engine as Stackexchange does.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite right, Artem.  I can't get math to function either.

@Rebecca Chernoff: Please let us know when this is resolved, so we can get started.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX does not seem to work in comments (see [here](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/it-only-looks-like-a-homework-problem/#comment-102)); or do we have to use `\( ... \)`?

Comment: Use \\( \\) for inline tex.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Maybe someone can edit my comment on the latest post, thanks! :>