# Latex not rendered and missing images in blog posts

Tags: support, bug, blog

LaTex code doesn't work for me for these pages:

- [Something you should know about: Quantifier Elimination (Part I)](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/something-you-should-know-about-quantifier-elimination-part-i/)
- [Something you should know about: Quantifier Elimination (Part II)](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/something-you-should-know-about-quantifier-elimination-part-ii)

tested with Chrome and Firefox.

Based on the comments in the 1st page and [another meta post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1203/19473) it seems the problem was before, however stopped working again I guess.

The 2nd page has some missing images, however they can be still retrieved from Archive.org, for example:

http://web.archive.org/http://web.mit.edu/abhatt/www/fig3.png

(copy the link manually, as it could not work when clicking on it)

So it's worth to re-upload them.

Comment: the community blog was abandoned over [3yr ago](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/status-of-our-community-blog). have long advocated its support/ maintenance. suggest volunteer(s) open a chat room. a recent success story/ related model to consider is the launch of [math.se] blog [here](http://math.blogoverflow.com/) and associated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room) launched/ sustained [over 1yr ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/a-community-blog-for-math-se)